# Using Spring Security with an external IDP

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a backend server for my applications. Actually, I'm using Keycloak as Identity Provider exploiting the OpenID Connect protocol. The frontend redirects users to Keycloak Login Page, so a token is returned to it. The frontend makes an authentication request to the backend using the returned token. Backend asks the IDP to validate the token and retrieve user info and roles.
Then I want to generate a JWT from the backend in order to easily authenticate the frontend requests.
Is this architecture fine? Or am I missing something important? Can I implement this architecture using Spring Security? Where can I learn more about it?
Thanks for any advice and support.

Comment: It sounds like you have an OAuth 2 resource server and an OAuth 2 client. Both of these are supported in Spring Security. You may find the Spring Security reference documentation helpful for getting started https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2

Comment: Sure but my backend can only provide authorization (so it's fine talking about oauth2 flow between client and server) but authentication is provided by an external server. Client is authenticated by the IDP and backend can provide an access token only by validating first client identity exploiting the IDP. So CustomAuthenticationProvider is needed instead of Spring Standard Authentication Providers. Am I right?